# Separate header file and its logic in c++

Tags: c++, g++, header-files

Please make me understand how header files works in C++. I am using osx and g++ compiler. I have

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream> 
#include "myfunc.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    square(10);
    return 0;
}
```

myfunc.hpp

```
#ifndef MYFUNC_HPP_
#define MYFUNC_HPP_

/*
void square(int x) {
    std::cout << x * x << std::endl;
};
*/
void square(int);

#endif // MYFUNC_HPP_
```

myfunc.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "myfunc.hpp"

using namespace std;

void square(int x) {
    cout << x * x << endl;
}
```

Now when I am trying to compile using **g++ main.cpp** , its giving

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "square(int)", referenced from:
>         _main in main-088331.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Because it is not able to find the function definition of **square** that is defined in myfunc.cpp.
But, if I defined square function in header file, it works because now it finds the function definition.

I want to use the function defined in myfunc.cpp in main.cpp, so I am using the header file myfunc.hpp. How can I achieve this? Am I doing something wrong here? Maybe my concept is not that clear about headers since I am new to C++ programming.

Comment: You need to include all the source files in your compilation string, not just `main.cpp`.

Comment: The `#include` is processed by the so-called preprocessor: cpp (run cpp main.cpp, you'll get it). It causes the included file to be some how copy-pasted inside your .cpp file. Once all the includes and processor directives replacedd, you get a translation unit. This file is then compiled to produce an object file: run g++ -c file.cpp => file.o. Then the object files are linked together using ld to produce a program. g++ is actulay a driver that run all these steps. To perform the last link phase, it must know all object file to produces: g++ main.cpp myfunc.cpp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `g++ main.cpp`, the compiler will try to compile *and link* the program, yet for linking, it lacks the source- or object file containing the definition of `square`. So it could compile `main.cpp` based on the function prototype given in the header file, yet it cannot link then.

To just compile `main.cpp` write

```
g++ -c main.cpp
```

To compile and link the complete program write:

```
g++ main.cpp myfunc.cpp
```

For more details concerning programs comprising several translation units confer, for example, [this link](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/howto/g++compiling.txt).